# Discover all vertices of a type from origin

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm modeling a permission system with graph-database.
This is an example scenario:

[image: graph image for example]

An user `u1` has a direct permission and also is in a group `g1` that has permissions and extends another group.

An user also `manage`s a system `s1` and can give the permissions related to `s1` to another users.

Basically what I need to do is get all permissions for my `u1`.
I suspected it is a simple query but I'm having a hard time with gremlin.

I have tried combinations of `repeat()`s, `out()`s, `emit()`s, `path()`s, etc. but couldn't find what I need. All I have tried returns either more nodes than needed (like the group nodes that are in the path of the permission, or the permissions related to the system) or fewer nodes (like not reaching `G2`)

So to sumarize what I need is:

```
gremlin> g.V('u1').__misteriousQueryThatShouldntBeThatHard()
==> v[p1]
==> v[p2]
==> v[p3]
==> v[p4]
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: do the vertex colors indicate that they have the same label?

Comment: What was the issue with Kfir's answer from your previous question?  I tested it, it seems to work fine on this use-case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only issue with Kfir's answer from the previous question is to limit the path to certain edge labels you can try:

```
g.V('u1')
    .repeat(out('is-in', 'extends', 'has-permission').simplePath())
    .until(hasLabel('Permission'))
```

Comment: Noam you were right. The problem with previous question was just this. I have tried `out(not(too))` but haven't tried passing more labels -_-. And I still couldn't test the performance of the other answer that's why it is not replied. Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoMenighin  If you want every label other than 'manage' you can do:  ````outE().not(hasLabel('manage')).inV() ````

Comment: Great Noam! One more question: some scenarios I would like to get the user itself and its permissions in one query, to avoid hitting the database more than needed. So the output in my example should have the permission nodes and the user node (`v[u1]`). Do you know if that's possible? I tried `emit()` right after the `g.V('u1')` but it emits more than only the user. Maybe using `sideEffect`..?

Comment: You can use ````union( identity(), repeat(....)...)```` or ````project```` step